# Картинка прижимается из за display в середину

Tags: html, css

Как сделать чтобы она была справа?

```css
.top {
    background: rgba(128, 128, 128, 0.3);
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    background-size: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 100px;
    border: 2px solid white;
}

.settings {
    width: 65px;
    height: 57px;
    float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="top">
    <button class="button">Главная</button>
    <button class="button">Магазин</button>
    <button class="button">О нас</button>
    <button class="button">Жуткий лес</button>
    <button class="button">Калькулятор</button>
    <a href="#zatemnenie"><img src="../Img/General/Set%20Black.png" class="settings" alt="Перезагрузите страницу"></a>
</div>
```

Изначально картинка была справа, но после добавления display (класс top) стала идти как кнопка. Как это обойти?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
a {
  margin-left: auto;
}
```

```css
.top {
    background: rgba(128, 128, 128, 0.3);
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    background-size: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 100px;
    border: 2px solid white;
}

.settings {
    width: 65px;
    height: 57px;
    float: right;
}

a {
  margin-left: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="top">
    <button class="button">Главная</button>
    <button class="button">Магазин</button>
    <button class="button">О нас</button>
    <button class="button">Жуткий лес</button>
    <button class="button">Калькулятор</button>
    <a href="#zatemnenie"><img src="../Img/General/Set%20Black.png" class="settings" alt="Перезагрузите страницу"></a>
</div>
```